# How to check if a value has more than 2 decimal digits

Tags: vb6

Good day.. Just want to ask, is there away to check 
if the value has more than 2 decimal digits..?

Hope to hear from you soon..

Thanks,

Link

Comment: There is [no need to add an extra signature](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) to your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the round function and compare it to the original number. So...

```
Function MoreThan2Digits(N As Single) As Boolean
    MoreThan2Digits = (N - Round(N, 2)) <> 0
End Function
```

Comment: I didn't even think about a negative number. Corrected function. Thanks @Brian